# How to unit test with a mocked file object in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, mocking

I have a class which I instantiate by giving a file name like `parser = ParserClass('/path/to/file')`, then I call `parser.parse()` method which opens and reads the file.
Now I want to unit test that if something bad happening inside:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
    // do something
```

the correct Exception will be raised, so I want to mock the `__builtin__.open` like this:

```
from mock import MagicMock, patch
from StringIO import StringIO

test_lines = StringIO("""some test lines, emulating a real file content""")
mock_open = MagicMock(return_value=test_lines)
with patch('__builtin__.open', mock_open):
    self.mock.parse()
```

but this gives me an `AttributeError: StringIO instance has no attribute '__exit__'`.
I tought StringIO behaves exactly like a file object, but it seems, this is not the case.

How could I test this method with a given content (test_lines) with mock objects? What should I use instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could subclass `StringIO` to provide a context manager:

```
class ContextualStringIO(StringIO):
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.close() # icecrime does it, so I guess I should, too
        return False # Indicate that we haven't handled the exception, if received


test_lines = ContextualStringIO(...)
```

---

Gross speculation: if `StringIO` objects are drop-in replacements for `file` objects *except* for the lack of a context manager, I wonder if this would work:

```
class ContextualStringIO(StringIO, file):
    pass
```

`ContextualStringIO` inherits what file operations it can from `StringIO`, but everything else is inherited from `file`. It looks elegant, but probably requires extensive testing (or someone more familiar with Python internals to explain why this wouldn't work).

Comment: `TypeError: __exit__() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)`

Comment: @Walkman: Thanks. I've updated it to take an arbitrary number of arguments, since I'm not going to handle any of the exceptions that might be received by `__exit__`. A proper implementation should; I'm not familiar enough with the context manager provided by `open` to know if it handles any exceptions, or if it simply closes the file and allows any exceptions to be re-raised.

Comment: [From the documentation:](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with)
If the suite was exited due to an exception, and the return value from the __exit__() method was false, the exception is reraised. If the return value was true, the exception is suppressed, and execution continues with the statement following the with statement.

Comment: Now that I read about context managers in the python documentation and looked the implementation of StringIO I think your solution is perfect and simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This is a known issue that `StringIO` does not implement the context manager protocol.

A [common recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576650-with-statement-for-stringio/) is the following:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def StringIO():
    """Add support for 'with' statement to StringIO - http://bugs.python.org/issue1286
    """
    try:
        from cStringIO import StringIO
    except ImportError:
        from StringIO import StringIO

    sio = StringIO()

    try:
        yield sio
    finally:
        sio.close()
```

It implements the context manager protocol for `StringIO` and allows it to be used in a `with` statement.

---

**UPDATE** Well, I just discovered the existence of [`mock_open`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/helpers.html?highlight=any#mock-open) which can directly read from a string, so it's probably the way to go.

Comment: Thanks! This works, but you should add `def StringIO(data)` and `sio = StringIO(data)` to be able to construct it with a parameter.

Comment: Just to stress again, the update is important, `mock_open` is meant for this purpose, and in spite of http://bugs.python.org/issue21258 it should be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use the [`io.StringIO` from the Standard Library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html):

> The io module provides the Python interfaces to stream handling. Under
>   Python 2.x, this is proposed as an alternative to the built-in file
>   object, but in Python 3.x it is the default interface to access files
>   and streams.

However (as the Note says) this can be used only with `unicode` type.

Answer (score 1):

There is [a provision](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/helpers.html?highlight=any#mock-open), specifically for this purpose in the `mock` library:

It does have an [issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue21258) in missing support for default iterator (ie. `__iter__` method, so you can't do `for line in opened_mock_file` straight away), but it can be worked around as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24779923/860421).

I have upvoted @icecrime's answer, but I feel his update part doesn't seem to be highlighted enough.