# Mock_open CSV file not getting any data

Tags: python, csv, mocking

I am trying to unit test a piece of code:

```
def _parse_results(self, file_name):
    results_file = open(file_name)
    results_data = list(csv.reader(results_file))
    index = len(results_data[1])-1
    results_file.close()
    return float(results_data[1][index])
```

by using mock_open like so:

```
@mock.patch('path.open', mock.mock_open(read_data='test, test2, test3, test4'))
def test_parse_results(self):
    cut = my_class(emulate=True)
    self.assertEqual(VAL, cut._parse_results('file'))
```

The problem I am running into is that I do not get any data when running csv.reader. If I run results_file.readlines() I get 'test, test2, test3, test4' which means that mock_open is working properly. But when I run csv.reader(results_file) I lose all the data.

Comment: I think this is because the csv is actually a _csv.c, a compiled c module, so it looks like the mocks are not carried over?

Answer (score 11):

This is because `mock_open` doesn't implement every feature that a file has, and notably not some of the ones that `csv` needs.

`mock_open` implements the methods `read()`, `readline()` and `readlines()`, and works both as a function and when called as a context manager (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open), whereas `csv.reader` works with…

> any object which supports the iterator protocol and returns a string each time its `__next__()` method is called — file objects and list objects are both suitable
>
> — https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader

Note that `mock_open` doesn't implement the `__next__()` method, and doesn't raise `StopIteration` when the end is reached, so it won't work with `csv.reader`.

The solution, as @Emily points out in her answer, is to turn the file into a list of its lines. This is possible because `mock_open` implements `readlines()`, and the resulting list *is* suitable for reading into `csv.reader` as the documentation says.

Comment: Another solution to testing csv.reader (and csv.DiscReader) is to implement the __next__() method on the MagicMock mock_open returns. As seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24779923/484127

Comment: Agreed. Implementing `__next__()` is a tidy approach.

Answer (score 4):

This really got me too, and was a nightmare to pinpoint.  To use your example code, this works

```
results_data = list(csv.reader(results_file.read()))
```

and this works

```
results_data = list(csv.reader(results_file.readlines()))
```

but this doesn't work

```
results_data = list(csv.reader(results_file))
```

using Python 3.4.

It seems counter to the documented interface of `csv.reader` so maybe an expert can elaborate on why.